# My Rectangle moves up despite what key I press with key Listener in Java

Tags: java, swing, draw, game-development, keylistener

I am generally a very bad programmer but have been trying to learn game development for a school project. My problem is that I have a draw method that draws a white rectangle and have a key Listener for movement but for some reason it moves upward despite what key I press not just W A S and D.
If you could help with this I would appreciate.
thanks

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    final int screenHeight = 600;
    final int screenWidth = 800;
    final int playerSize = 48;
    int fps = 60;
    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread;
    
//player default position
     int playerX = 100;
     int playerY = 100;
     int playerSpeed = 1;

        
    
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (screenWidth, screenHeight)); 
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }
        
        public void startGameThread() {
            gameThread = new Thread (this);
            gameThread.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/fps; // 0.01666 seconds = 60 times per seconds
        double nextDrawTime = System.nanoTime() + drawInterval;
        while(gameThread != null) {
            System.out.println("this gmae is runing");
            // update information such as character positions
            // draw the screen with the updated information
            update();
            repaint();
            try {
                double remainingTime = nextDrawTime - System.nanoTime();
                remainingTime = remainingTime/1000000;
                if(remainingTime<0) {
                    remainingTime = 0;
                }
                Thread.sleep ((long) remainingTime);
                
                nextDrawTime += drawInterval;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    private void update() {
        if(keyH.upPressed ==true) {
            playerY = playerY - playerSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.downPressed ==true){
            playerY = playerY + playerSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.leftPressed== true){
            playerX = playerX - playerSpeed;
        }
        else if (keyH.rightPressed == true) {
            playerX = playerX +playerSpeed;
        }
        
    }

    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // to draw something
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerSize, playerSize);
        g2.dispose(); 
        
    }
}
```

```
package game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public  class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {

    public boolean leftPressed;
    public boolean rightPressed;
    public boolean upPressed;
    public boolean downPressed;
    public boolean spacePressed;
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D);{
            rightPressed = true;
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A);{
            leftPressed = true;
        }


        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W);{
            upPressed = true;
        }
    
    
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S);{
            downPressed = true;
        }
    

    
    }
    

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D);{
            rightPressed = false;
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A);{
            leftPressed = false;
        }


        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W);{
            upPressed = false;
        }
    
    
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S);{
            downPressed = false;
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A);{` <- remove the `;` after your if statements. `if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A); { ... }` is equal to `if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {;} { ... }` - meaning your actual if-body-block is just a no-op and what you think your if-bodies are is always executed unconditionally.

Comment: In other words, if this is the way that you want to wire your code, first set all those booleans to false at the top of your keyPressed methods, and then within the method you will set the correct boolean to true. Note that it is almost always better to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) than to use a KeyListener.